# Accessing element in list

Tags: python

I would like to know how to get the elements from the list, maybe using for loop?

Here is the code that can save all the angles into myList[]

```
myList = []

for num in range(1,totalStop+1):
    in_features = "C:/Users/Desktop/fyp/fyp.gdb/sampleline"
    out_feature_class = "C:/Users/Desktop/fyp/output.gdb/samplelineTemp"    
    where = '"OBJECTID" = ' + "%d" %num
    
    # Execute Select
    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, where)


    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_feature_class, ["OID@", "SHAPE@","streetnam", "angle"]):
            # Print the current line ID
            print "Walk along",row[2]
            
            #Set start point
            startpt = row[1].firstPoint

            #Set Start coordinates
            startx = startpt.X
            starty = startpt.Y

            #Set end point
            endpt = row[1].lastPoint
            
            #Set End coordinates
            endx = endpt.X
            endy = endpt.Y
        
            #print startx, starty, endx, endy        

            value = row[3]                
                       
            #append all the angles of line into myList
            if value not in myList:
                myList.append(value)
```

after append(value), now myList contain all angles(azimuth) of the lines.

mylist[]=
-91.3478982503
-3.51652064715
-124.295923979
31.1849858238
43.8914254459
-59.4335738611
111.914929118
69.5778228682

The thing I would like to calculate is the first angle(myList[0]) minus the second angle (mylist[1]), return the value. Then the second angle(myList[1]) minus the third angle (mylist[2]), return the value.

Can you tell me how to perform the above steps?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
deltas = []
for i in range(0,len(myList)-2):
    deltas.append(myList[i]-myList[i+1])
for delta in deltas:
   #do something with each delta
```